# Moq Verify not checking if a method was called

Tags: moq

Hi I am getting an error and I don't understand why

```
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            visitService = new Mock<IVisitService>();
            visitRepository = new Mock<IVisitRepository>();
            visitUIService = new VisitUIService(visitRepository.Object, visitService.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        public void  VisitUIService_CanSoftDelete()
        {
            Mock<IVisitEntity> mockVisitEntity = new Mock<IVisitEntity>();

            visitService = new Mock<IVisitService>();
            visitRepository.Setup(x => x.GetVisitsByDocumentLineItems(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<int>>())).Returns(new List<IVisitEntity>() { mockVisitEntity.Object});

            visitUIService.DeleteVisits(new VisitDeletionModel());

            visitService.Verify(x => x.SoftDeleteVisit(It.IsAny<IVisitEntity>()),Times.AtLeastOnce());
        }
```

Invocation was not performed on the mock: x => x.SoftDeleteVisit(IsAny())

I can't fix this I added visitService.Setup(x => x.SoftDeleteVisit(mockVisitEntity.Object)).Verifiable(); and a few other variations of the parameters but no luck

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the consuming object visitUIService is already been initialized with the intial mocked interfaces and the setup that you are doing later is not useful.

Two approaches:

a) move the initialization of the class to the test i.e after the interface is setup

b) Lazy Load the mocks as follows, but you need to modify your class for the same using Func or Lazy. I will show it using Func

```
visitUIService = new VisitUIService(()=>visitRepository.Object, ()=>visitService.Object);
```